# Override method onExpand and onCollapse doesn't works on libs SlideExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, onclicklistener

I'm trying to use the SlideExpandableListView library ([link](https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView)) for Android and I've a problem to manage the button that expand the listview...
In the source code there is an abstract class (AbstractSlideExpandableListAdapter.java) with a listener, but I don't know how I can implements in my code...

I've tryied this code but doesn't works:

```
AbstractSlideExpandableListAdapter manageclick = new SlideExpandableListAdapter(adapter);
        manageclick .setItemExpandCollapseListener(new AbstractSlideExpandableListAdapter.OnItemExpandCollapseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onExpand(View itemView, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"I'm here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCollapse(View itemView, int position) {

            }
        });
```

Can you help me? Thanks!!

Comment: I can't understand well the problem, you only need an ListView, your adapter,  wrap the adapter with the class SlideExpandableListAdapter, and set your adapter to the ListView.

Comment: Yes, I have an adapter etc... but I need to manage the onExpand event! :)
I know that is implemented on library but I don't know how can I call this event. Thanks!

Comment: I remember using this library in a project, but don't remember how to implement such functionality. I think you can implement a listener on the View that is performing the action of expanding in the adapter.
If you need to perform an action in the Activity when a row is expanded, you can add an interface on your adapter as if it were Fragments and implement the same methods in the Activity to work as callbacks.[link](http://www.aprendiendodeandroidymas.com/2013/08/como-customizamos-nuestras-vistas-con.html)

Comment: 3 months ago, was added a listener to manage this event. The listener is written in AbstractSlideExpandableListAdapter.java but I don't understand how can I add in my code... :)

Comment: And if you add a OnItemClickListener to your ActionSlideExpandableListView, and that you handle the View? Anyway, as @MaxLebold says, I would handle it from the adapter. [Adapters](http://www.aprendiendodeandroidymas.com/2013/08/como-customizamos-nuestras-vistas-con.html)

Comment: I posted an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780292/slide-down-effect-on-expandablelistview/25647564#25647564 Hoep it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you like to react on the buttom-click?

For a ExpandbleListview you dont need to expand or callapse the groups by yourself.

Or is there any other intention?

Comment: Thanks for reply! :)
I needed to drastically change the look of the list view item when it was expanded...

Comment: I do that on the adapter

Comment: Me too. This is the perfect place for it. In the adapter. You have there this method:  getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) -> here you can act like you want if "isExpanded" is true or false. :)

Comment: Mmm, interesting! Sorry for insisting, but I ask you a last question: Can you write a little sample code to see your solution, please? Thanks to all! You're awesome!

Comment: You can see this [Expandablelistview with custom adapter](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-expandablelistview-with-custom-adapter-baseexpandablelistadapter.html) I wrote about it, but in Spanish, anyway at the end of the post there are several very useful links in English about Adapters [Adapters](http://www.aprendiendodeandroidymas.com/2013/08/como-customizamos-nuestras-vistas-con.html)