# android Expandable List view slide up down animation for child view

Tags: expandablelistview

I want to animate slide up slide down animation on expandable list view. when I click the group Item, It will expand the child view and collapse it.In the get Child view method I am populating the child views.

The following code to populate child views.

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, 
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    Log.i(TAG, "getChildView"); 
    if (convertView == null) { 
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child, null); 
    } 
    View toolbar = convertView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar); 
    setAnimationView(toolbar); 
    ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) 
toolbar.getLayoutParams()).bottomMargin = -75; 
    toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
    ExpandAnimation expandAni = new ExpandAnimation(toolbar, 1000); 
    toolbar.startAnimation(expandAni); 
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childTo); 
    tv.setText(text); 
    return convertView; 
}
```

How can I solve my problem.please help...
Thanks & Regards,
Venkatesan.R

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution to the problem ?

Comment: Hi Swayam, I am working on Calendar with gridview ,Rightnow I have implemented gesture listener for left and right swipe,All are working fine , But using onsingletapconfirmed i could not able to get the position of the selected item in the griview. It remains position 0 on all selected item in the Gridview.I tried with the below code

int j = gridview.pointToPosition((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());

Please help to me solve the problem.

Comment: Actually even I was looking for a similar animation and ended up using https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView/. I am not sure how to get the position of the click though.

Comment: @VenkatesanRamdoss can you please explain what is the problem? do you want to add animations for the child-views when you expand the groups?

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply.Currently I am displaying current week in the gridview,When a user swipe down it will display the whole month.My requirement is I need to do animation for slide down and slide up.When a user swipe down i need to apply the slide down animation with the whole month.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I recently just wrote an widget for doing exactly what you've asked for. I've released the source code here:
[Android ExpandableListView using animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627113/android-expandablelistview-using-animation)

I may improve the implementation and add comments in the future, but the main idea will stay the same. Take a look at this post if you are interested in how it works: [Android ExpandableListView using animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627113/android-expandablelistview-using-animation).

Answer (score 0):

the `ListView` classes are made for performance for a great number of rows with just in time drawing while sliding. so animation is no goal of this kind of view and not that easy. 
maybe something like `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` could work.
you can also take a look here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736302/add-animation-in-expandable-listview)