# Expandable listview with cursor

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

i want to make an expandable listview, but the adapter will take cursor as input instead of array list.

i would like to implement animation on collapse, 
https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView/

i refereed this lib, i'm now am able to implement listview by passing list to the adapter. But is there a tweak we 
can do so that, this adapter can make it work with cursor?.

My expanded child list consists of only icons. Data will sit in group view