# Is there any way to style the Expandable ListView in Android with Material Design?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-design-library

There is an expandable listview widget in Android but it doesn't seem to have been updated with material design styling/specs. Is there anything I can do to make it so that it has material design styles and animations?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I really don't know what you expect and what does Material Design means to you, so I would like to recommend you this great tutorial:

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Material-Design-Primer

where you may find an answer how to stylish Expandable to be more Material.

EDIT: Thanks for explanation. Now I can suggest you some posts which might be useful for you. First, check this issue

[Android ExpandableListView using animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627113/android-expandablelistview-using-animation)

[Animation for expandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385567/animation-for-expandablelistview)

you would find here some animations like for expanding list.

If you have any question,  please free to ask.

Comment: The expandable listview widget doesn't have the material animation where the dropdown toggle rotates to an up arrow or down arrow. It also doesn't have the smooth animation for expanding and collapsing. Even the icon that's being used for the indicator doesn't seem to be the Material Design version. That's what I mean by Material Design styling/specs.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try to modify expandablelistview using your suggestions